# Detecting black/gray elements in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, pixel

You guys know how to detect/return the points of all black/grayish element in an image?
If possible, please include any tutorial codes for me.

Edit: I've made a thresholded image from the source "img". and I'm trying to make all the colored pixel into white.

```
for(x=0; x<img->width; x++) {
  for(y=0;y<img->height; y++) {
    uchar* temp_ptr = &((uchar*)(img_result_threshold->imageData + img_result_threshold->widthStep*y))[x];
    s = cvGet2D(img_hsv, y, x);
    if(s.val[1] >= 100 && s.val[2] >= 100) {
      temp_ptr[0]=255; //White to greater of threshold
      printf("Point(%d, %d) = (%.1f, %.1f, %.1f)\n", x, y, s.val[0], s.val[1], s.val[2]);
    } else {
      temp_ptr[0]=0; //Black other
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've already done getting the element value of each pixel, I've planning to separate the colored to gray elements.
I think my first work is wrong so sorry if i'm not going to post it.

Comment: OK great so please show us a little bit of code where you would like to insert the hypothetical gray-detection functionality.  Better if we can work from what you have rather than giving you some code that may not integrate well with what you've already written.

Comment: for(x=0; x<img->width; x++)
 {
  for(y=0;y<img->height; y++)
  {
   uchar* temp_ptr = &((uchar*)(img_result_threshold->imageData + img_result_threshold->widthStep*y))[x];

   s = cvGet2D(img_hsv, y, x);

   if(s.val[1] >= 100 && s.val[2] >= 100){
    temp_ptr[0]=255;//White to greater of threshold
    printf("Point(%d, %d) = (%.1f, %.1f, %.1f)\n", x, y, s.val[0], s.val[1], s.val[2]);
   }
            else{
    temp_ptr[0]=0;//Black other
   }
  }
 }

here it is. I've made a thresholded image from the source "img". and I'm trying to make all the colored pixel into white.

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't able to answer my questions with my current reputation.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The only right thing it do is to detect the element value of each pixel.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the input image is in 24 bit format i.e. R G B then a pixel is greyscale if all three values (R G and B) are the same.

So loop through the image, check if the current pixel's R, G and B elements have the same value and if they don't then set the pixel to white.

You will then be left with an image with just the greyscale pixels.

If you want just dark grey pixels, then when you check to see if RGB values are the same you can do a second check to see if the value is less than say 127 (or whatever you want the threshold to be).

Comment: There is also a case that a gray pixel is consist of unequal values of RGB. ie (100, 99, 98), it also appears to be gray in images, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think they are technically grey values but if you want to include them, then it would be easy to check if the RGB values fall within x of each other i.e. in the example above they are 1/2 away from each other

Comment: Ok sir. But is there a better way if i will convert the image into HSV first?

Comment: I imagine you can do something similar with HSV, however I'm probably not the authority to ask on that one.

Comment: Ok thanks sir. I guess i'm gonna try it myself.
But, is it ok if i will use the saturation and value(brightness) element of the image to classify the pixel?

Comment: As i mentioned previously, my knowledge of the hsv colour space isn't great so i'm not the best person to ask, but theres no harm in experimenting and seeing what happens. If it doesn't work then you can use RGB instead

Answer (score -2):

1. Convert the color image into gray image first by the following, provided your image is RGB

   cvtColor(im_rgb,im_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);
2. Convert the image into binary using your threshold, say 127

   cvThreshold(im_gray, im_bw, 127, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

Comment: I believe he/she is trying to extract the grey pixels from a colour image, not convert the entire image to greyscale

Comment: Use the above code will produce a mask image that marks all the grey pixels as 255 so that if he/she wants to extract those pixels, the positions will be known. It all depends on his/her purpose. But to check a colored pixel is grey or not, it's better to convert it to grey pixel first.

Comment: But surely if you are converting colour pixels to grey pixels then some of the grey pixels you keep will originally have been colour